# please explain this statement(cout << 1 + int((a < b) ^ ((b - a) & 1)) << endl)

Tags: c++

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t;
    cin >> t;
    while (t--) {
        int a, b;
        cin >> a >> b;
        if (a == b) cout << 0 << endl;
        else cout << 1 + int((a < b) ^ ((b - a) & 1)) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

please someone describe the above statement.how this statement works and what is the result of this statement.
    this code is snippet from codeforces.
    link:https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/74224

Comment: Do read [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/5910058)

Comment: I say, when in doubt, simplify.

Comment: R Sahu good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make it step by step.

1. `c = (b - a) & 1` - check if last bit of `b - a` is set, same as check that `b - a` is odd.
2. `d = (a < b) ^ c` - returns true if `int(a < b) != c`.
3. `1 + int(d)` - should be clear

Then we have

```
             (b - a) - odd          (b - a) - even
(a < b)           1                       2
(a >= b)          2                       1
```

Comment: I wonder why the author wasted lines... Instead of `if`-`else`, she/he could've written: `std::cout << (a != b) * (1 + int((a < b) ^ ((b - a) & 1))) << std::endl;`. ;-)

Comment: In your line 2, the conversion actually goes the other way. The type of `a < b` is `bool` and the type of `c` is `int`, so `a < b` gets promoted to `int`, with the value `0` or `1`. It doesn't affect the result here, since `c` is 0 or 1, but be very careful when comparing `bool` values with `int` values. `int i = 2; if (i) f();` will call `f()`, but `int i = 2; if (i == true) f();` will not.